# Install apt packages in docker via build step and copy

Tags: dockerfile, apt

When you have a complicated `RUN apt-get install` section that you reuse over multiple docker images, what is the best way to reuse it?

The options that I think we have are

- copy-paste the `RUN` command *n* times across your Dockerfiles (this is what I do today)
- make a docker image and use it as a build step + `COPY --from=builder...` (**this is what I wan't, but I don't konw how to do it**).

I am thinking of something like this:

1. Dockerfile with reusable apt install command, tagged as `my-builder-img`:

```
FROM debian:buster
RUN ... apt-get install ...
```

2. Dockerfile that reuses that complicated install:

```
FROM my-builder-img as builder
#nothing here
FROM debian:buster
COPY --from=builder /usr/bin:/usr/bin # (...???)
```

TL;DR how to reuse apt-get install from a previus image onto a new image.

Comment: It would be great to have a good way to do this, if you do it right you could avoid the awkwardness of deleting install cache. Maybe you could do something with dpkg-query --listfiles?

Answer (score 1):

I was also after this answer, as this helps complex multistage builds better leverage inline cache (which we use in our CI). We want to always install apt packages before any step that can have its cache affected by a previous stage in the build.

One solution is brute force. In you Dockerfile you could do:

```
FROM debian:buster as my-image 
<build the image>

FROM debian:buster as my-other-image
COPY --from=my-image / /
```

as, from [the COPY docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

> The COPY instruction copies new files or directories from `<src>` and adds them to the filesystem of the container at the path `<dest>`.

emphasis on *new*

another solution is using `dpkg-query --listfiles`
e.g. after building my image, I ran the following inside the image:

```
dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}' | xargs dpkg --listfiles | cut -d "/" -f2 | sort | uniq
```

which gave something like:

```
bin
boot
dev
...
```

for each of these you could have a statement under your latter build stages like:

```
COPY --from=my-image /bin /bin
COPY --from=my-image /boot /boot
...
```

Both solutions seem to work fine in my testing, but for some reason the

```
COPY --from=my-image / /
```

solution is really slow on my local machine >10 minutes but fast on our CI <30s.

Answer (score -1):

You just use the image you put all the packages in directly.

Multi-stage builds shine when you are creating an artifact and copying that to a new image. If you are just installing packages those will exist in the image.

Dockerfile with packages you want:

```
FROM debian:buster
RUN ... apt-get install ...
```

Tag it as `my-image`.

Now, just use that image in other Dockerfiles and the packages installed will be available.

```
FROM my-image:latest
# other directives...
```

Comment: the thing here is that not all images will have all of the packages, I want in this case the `gcloud` library for working with google cloud, but I don't want my base image to contain gcloud, just some of them

Comment: So define an image `my-base` with most of the packages you want. Then in your project you can create a dockerfile which has `FROM my-base` and install the additional packages.